# Cannot redirect Ionos microsoft hosted website to https automatically

Tags: html, asp.net, ssl, redirect

The IONOS help here https://www.ionos.co.uk/help/ssl-certificates/tips-for-setup-and-use/automatically-redirect-visitors-to-ssl-secured-site/ tells me to do the following:

> Steps for Windows Packages
> Open a basic text editor, such as Notepad (Windows) or TextEdit (MacOS).
> Copy and Paste the code below into the text editor.

```
<%EnableSessionState=False
host = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")

if host = "example.com" or host = "www.example.com" then
response.redirect("https://www.example.com/")

else
response.redirect("https://www.example.com/error.htm")

end if
%>mixed
```

> In the text editor, replace all instances of "example.com" with your own domain.
> Save the file as index.asp.
> Upload the File via FTPS to the root of your webspace.

But if I do this, I get an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error message when I type in the address of the website. It tells me to cleardown cookies, which I have done, but that makes no difference. Plus other devices - other PCs, laptops and phones have the same problem.

I made sure there is an error.htm page.

The SSL certificate is valid and there is no problem if you type in the address preceded by https:// - BEFORE implementing OR AFTER reversing the  IONOS advice.

I just want is to automatically go to the https version - even if you do not prefix the address with https://.

I have tried editing the web.config but it seems I cannot get this right.  - have tried this code for example. Amended to my web address of course.

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
         <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
             <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

And get this error::
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Also tried this - no luck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My homepage is index.htm so I thought it was strange that the Ionos code recommends creating a .asp page to? But what do I know ---- not much apparently.

Ionos will not help - they say it is outside of their scope.

Comment: Also tried this

Comment: Amazingly, the solution to this question provided the missing part of the puzzle that I was trying to solve on-and-off for more than a year. [I figured out how to stop too many redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60286204/335858) at the expense of not forcing users to https; now I know how to force them back. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I did put effort into researching this (ref the amount of detail above) - so I am disappointed that it got marked down.

But it seems someone in Ionos took pity on me. And put this  .htaccess file below in the root of the site.

I did look at this but I could not find the .htaccess file.

THANKYOU!

Contents of .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

I edited this to remove a "/"  here  _HOST}*/*$1 - line 3
This was adding an extra /to the end of the web address in MS Edge.  See [Why do I have double slashes at the end of my website URL like this: //](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64604068/why-do-i-have-double-slashes-at-the-end-of-my-website-url-like-this)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R,L]
```